# load data in two table views + segmented control _ ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uisegmentedcontrol

I am developing an application in objective c to list data in table views.

Now, In one of the views i have a view controller inside which there is a segmented control and 2 table views . I want to load different data in different table views.

Lets call both the table views as view 1 and view 2

But i have only one UIViewController Class to load data.View 1 is loaded by default in view controller and on tap of segmented view control, the views are hidden and shown. i am reloading the table in both views as soon as the segmented view control is tapped.

here is the code :
Segment view action :

```
- (IBAction)MESegmentValueChanged:(UISegmentedControl *)sender {
    switch (sender.selectedSegmentIndex) {
        case 0:
            self.EventTableView.hidden=NO;
            self.MeTableView.hidden =YES;
            [self.EventTableView reloadData];
            break;
        case 1:
            self.EventTableView.hidden =YES;
            self.MeTableView.hidden =NO;
            [self.MeTableView reloadData];
            break;
        default:
//            self.EventTableView.hidden=NO;
//            self.MeTableView.hidden =YES;
//            [self.MeTableView reloadData];

            break;
    }
```

table view cellForRowAtIndexPath :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSLog(@"%@",tableView);
    if (tableView==self.MeTableView) {
      // load data in view 2
        return cell1;
    }
    else if (tableView==self.EventTableView)  {
    //load data in view 1
       return cell1;
    }
    else{
       // load data in view 1
        return cell1;
    }
}
```

Comment: so what exactly doesn't work ? Have you hooked up both tables views datasource ?

Comment: Regarding the hiding, is there only ever one table view visible at a time? Is there ever a case where both are visible?

Comment: What's the question?  (If you have your dataSource and delegate set up for both views, your tests of `tableView==` should tell you what data you need.)

Comment: @ All : Thanks i am implementing things and get back in case of any issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use tags to solve your problem:

```
if (tableView.tag == 1)
{
  ....
  return cell;
}
else if (tableView.tag == 2)
{
  ....
  return cell;
}
```

don't forget to set tag indexes in your storyboard or code.